# Send keys conditionally using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I use the following script to play a playlist using media player classic while sending a Ctrl-4 to the window.

```
mpc-hc.exe playlist.m3u /play
[void][System.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('system.Windows.forms')
Foreach ($line in get-content 
playlist.m3u) {
If ($line.substring($line.length-5,1) -match 2) {
 [System.Windows.forms.Sendkeys]::sendwait("^4")
  }
}
```

The shortcut Ctrl-4 displays information on the file played, but I want it only for the second file, this script does it for all the files played, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code so you can debug in ISE or VSCode.
Like:

```
$files = Get-Content playlist.m3u
```

and

```
$file = $files[1] # the 2nd one
```

Then perhaps you do not need a `foreach`.  Without more context, it is hard to provide a full solution, and perhaps the above is enough info to unblock you.

EDIT per comment that changes the requirements...

Adapt your code to something like:

```
$files = @(
'one'
'two'
'three'
'four'
'five'
)

$isEvenIndex = $false
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($isEvenIndex) 
    { 
        # do your stuff
        Write-Output "$file"
    }

    $isEvenIndex = !$isEvenIndex
}
```

Comment: I used 2 as an example, the idea is the file has many lines and I want to see the info on even numbered files

Comment: Thanks but the Ctrl-v is still sent to all files, not just the even ones

Comment: Anyone else have a solution?